# Перезапуск Python программы

Tags: python, python-3.x, debian

Непрерывно выполняется Python-программа. Нужно перезапустить её через командную строку, либо через `subprocess.call()`.
Вручную, я бы это осуществил с помощью <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.
Есть какие либо аналоги?

Comment: Кто и где запускает программу? Есть ли возможность управлять методом запуска? Нужна ли интерактивность (ввод данных от пользователя) или достаточно запустить программу в фоне с лог-файлом? Для чего вам нужно её перезапускать?

Comment: Обычный бот который работает на потоках в фоне.
Нужно перезапустить его через subprocess.call()

Comment: Почему вам нужен именно subprocess?

Comment: Потому что перезапуск нужно вызвать изнутри, subprocess позволяет это сделать

Comment: Просто сделайте выключение бота, а что-нибудь снаружи пусть запустит его заново после выключения, без всяких subprocess

Comment: `ctrl+c` - это фактически сигнал `sigint`. вот и пошлите его нужному процессу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотри на Systemd

Systemd запускает сервисы описанные в его конфигурации.
Конфигурация состоит из множества файлов, которые называются юнитами.

/etc/systemd/system/ - сохраняешь здесь свой юнит.

Описываешь три секции: [Unit], [Service], [Install]

Команды на старт/стоп и релоад сервиса:

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/bundle exec service -C /work/www/myunit/shared/config/service.rb --daemon
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/bundle exec service -S /work/www/myunit/shared/tmp/pids/service.state stop
ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/bundle exec service -S /work/www/myunit/shared/tmp/pids/service.state restart
```

Попросим systemd автоматически рестартовать наш сервис, если он вдруг перестанет работать.

```
Restart=always
```

Смотрим его статус

```
systemctl enable myunit - Разрешить сервис
systemctl status myunit - Проверка статуса
systemctl start myunit - Запуск сервиса
systemctl daemon-reload - Перезапуск сервиса
```